# How to move or position a legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I'm trying to create a ggplot2 plot with the legend beneath the plot.

The ggplot2 book says on p 112 "The position and justification of legends are controlled by the theme setting legend.position, and the value can be right, left, top, bottom, none (no legend), or a numeric position".

The following code works (since "right" it is the default), and it also works with "none" as the legend position, but "left", "top", "bottom", all fail with "Error in grid.Call.graphics("L_setviewport", pvp, TRUE) :  Non-finite location and/or size for viewport"

```
library(ggplot2)
(myDat <- data.frame(cbind(VarX=10:1, VarY=runif(10)), 
    Descrip=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE)))
qplot(VarX,VarY, data=myDat, shape=Descrip) + 
    opts(legend.position="right")
```

What am I doing wrong? Re-positioning a legend must be incredibly common, so I figure it's me.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

In versions > 0.9.3 (when `opts` was deprecated)

```
theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

---

**Older version:**

Unfortunately it's a bug in ggplot2 which I really really hope to fix this summer.

*Update:*

The bug involving `opts(legend.position = "left")` has been fixed using the most current version of **ggplot2**. In addition, version 0.9.0 saw the introduction of `guide_legend` and `guide_colorbar` which allow much finer control over the appearance and positioning of items within the legend itself. For instance, the ability specify the number of rows and columns for the legend items.

Comment: Isn't this done now with `theme_update(legend.position = "bottom")`?

Comment: @RuiVieira for `theme_update()`, see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html "Modify a single plot's theme using theme(); see theme_update() if you want modify the active theme, to affect all subsequent plots. "

Answer (score 25):

As Hadley mentioned, you can move a legend to the bottom with `theme(legend.position = "bottom")`

Or manually positioned using `theme(legend.position = c(.2,.85))`

If you want the legend to be horizontal, use `theme(legend.position = c(.2,.85), legend.direction = "horizontal")`

Answer (score 9):

In newer versions of `ggplot2`, you can use `+ theme(legend.position='bottom')`.

```
qplot(VarX,VarY, data=myDat, shape=Descrip) + 
  theme(legend.position='bottom')
```

[image]

See [Cookbook for R - Legends](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/) for more legends goodness.

In response to a comment, `theme_update()` doesn't kick in if invoked in the middle of a ggplot (as in `+ theme_update()`, only subsequent times.  It also modifies the active theme rather than just the specific plot.  So you could do this:

```
theme_update(legend.position='bottom')
qplot(VarX,VarY, data=myDat, shape=Descrip)
```

with results as above, with the difference being that subsequent plots will also default to legend on bottom.

Comment: with theme(legend.position="bottom") my legend appears bottom left while in your example it's shown in the middle (as I thought it to be in my previous plots over the years). Do you know if something about that changed and how to get it in the middle again?

Answer (score 5):

You can always place the legend manually - but since the label is still stacked/vertical, it kind of looks ugly. I really hope hadley finds time to fix this :-)

```
p <- qplot(VarX,VarY, data=myDat, shape=Descrip) + 
opts(legend.position=c(.5,0.9),plot.margin = unit(c(6,0,0,0), "lines"))
```

Comment: `opts()` is now deprecated - use `guide_legend()` instead. http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/guide_legend.html

Comment: You can call `legend.direction = "horizontal"` in `theme` argument.