# Automatically determine position of plot legend

Tags: r, automation, plot, ggplot2, gnuplot

You can position the key legend manually in most plotting programs. For example, in gnuplot it's done using `set key top right`. In ggplot2, it's done [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954005/how-to-move-or-position-a-legend-in-ggplot2).

Is there a plotting library, script, or simple algorithm that automatically positions the legend such that it overlaps the data in the plot minimally?

What I mean is: Suppose I plot the line `y=x`. A good place for the legend in that case would be top left or bottom right.

Comment: In R, I suspect the answer is no. But you're more likely to get the eyeballs of knowledgable R users with an [r] tag.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in a standalone solution (script or algorithm that I'll implement) that will accomplish this for any plotting program (my weapon of choice is `gnuplot`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
require(Hmisc)
?largest.empty
```

there are other discussions and functions proposed in R-help archives

Answer (score 6):

```
require(plotrix)

?emptyspace     # Find the largest empty space on a plot
```

This is the example from the help page:

```
x<-rnorm(100)
 y<-rnorm(100)
 plot(x,y,main="Find the empty space",xlab="X",ylab="Y")
 es<-plotrix::emptyspace(x,y)
 # use a transparent background so that any overplotted points are shown
 plotrix::boxed.labels(es,labels="Here is the\nempty space",bg="transparent")
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick trick to get one of `"topleft"`, `"topright"`, `"bottomleft"` and `"bottomright"`:

```
auto.legend.pos <- function(x,y,xlim=range(x),ylim=range(y)) {
  countIt <- function(a,zero.only=TRUE) {
    tl <- sum(x <= xlim[1]*(1-a)+xlim[2]*a & y >= ylim[1]*a+ylim[2]*(1-a))
    tr <- sum(x >= xlim[1]*a+xlim[2]*(1-a) & y >= ylim[1]*a+ylim[2]*(1-a))
    bl <- sum(x <= xlim[1]*(1-a)+xlim[2]*a & y <= ylim[1]*(1-a)+ylim[2]*a)
    br <- sum(x >= xlim[1]*a+xlim[2]*(1-a) & y <= ylim[1]*(1-a)+ylim[2]*a)
    c(topleft=tl,topright=tr,bottomleft=bl,bottomright=br)
  }
  for (k in seq(0.5,0.1,by=-0.05)) {
    a <- countIt(k)
    if (sum(a==0)>0) break
  }
  names(a)[which(a==0)][1]
}
```

Test:

```
plot(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length, data=iris)
auto.legend.pos(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Sepal.Length)
# [1] "topleft"
```

**EDIT**

`par("usr")` after `plot` returns the extremes of the user coordinates of the plotting regions: see `?par`. So we can change the function to:

```
auto.legend.pos <- function(x,y,xlim=NULL,ylim=NULL) {
  if (dev.cur() > 1) {
    p <- par('usr')
    if (is.null(xlim)) xlim <- p[1:2]
    if (is.null(ylim)) ylim <- p[3:4]
  } else {
    if (is.null(xlim)) xlim <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    if (is.null(ylim)) ylim <- range(y, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  countIt <- function(a) {
    tl <- sum(x <= xlim[1]*(1-a)+xlim[2]*a & y >= ylim[1]*a+ylim[2]*(1-a))
    tr <- sum(x >= xlim[1]*a+xlim[2]*(1-a) & y >= ylim[1]*a+ylim[2]*(1-a))
    bl <- sum(x <= xlim[1]*(1-a)+xlim[2]*a & y <= ylim[1]*(1-a)+ylim[2]*a)
    br <- sum(x >= xlim[1]*a+xlim[2]*(1-a) & y <= ylim[1]*(1-a)+ylim[2]*a)
    c(topleft=tl,topright=tr,bottomleft=bl,bottomright=br)
  }
  for (k in seq(0.5,0.1,by=-0.05)) {
    a <- countIt(k)
    if (sum(a==0)>0) break
  }
  names(a)[which(a==0)][1]   # may delete "[1]"
}

plot(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length, data=iris, xlim=c(1,5), ylim=c(3.5,6))
auto.legend.pos(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Sepal.Length)
# [1] "bottomright"
```

Comment: will get a bit messy if you have multiple curves to plot.